The entity type ModelName is not part of the model for the current context
The application runs without error in Visual Studio.
Published to the web server and run the app. The first model-driven view runs without issue. The second throws this error

The entity type DepartmentsTeamsLink is not part of the model for the current context

The code breaks on this line
var departmentTeamLink = db.DepartmentsTeamsLink
                           .Where(x => x.DepartmentId == departments.DepartmentId)
                           .Select(x => x.TeamId).ToList();

DepartmentsTeamsLink in the .edmx and the model is in the models list in VS. Again it runs without error in dev but fails in production. Dev and prod are hitting the same database.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Before the latest build, I had the same issue. I pre-compiled the publish and the issue resolved itself.  this time however the issue has persisted.
Any thoughts?
